# How to programatically create a DataGrid in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I create a DataGrid programatically in C# WPF? 
I could be generating multiple **DataGrids** with information  - depending on what the user selects

For example:

```
if(true)
{
  // Create a DataGrid programatically
  DataGrid DG = new DataGrid();
  DG.ColumnHeader 1 = "Name"
  DG.ColumnHeader 2 = "Age"

  // Load info to the datagrid from somewhere
  // Add under Name column the name "Fred" and "Tom"
  // Add under Age column "26" and "18"
  DG.FieldNameColumn.Row1 = "Fred"
  DG.Age.Row1 = "26"
  DG.FieldNameColumn.Row2 = "Tom"
  DG.Age.Row2 = " 18"
}
else
{
  // dont generate a DG ( don't do anything here)
}
```

Comment: If you're doing like this, how will the user control know where you want to place the DG? Why don't you create a user control and control the visibility of the grid instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with `MVVM`? I would recommend doing it the "right" way and create an associated `ViewModel` that holds a collection if items. The `DataGrid` will then bind to that collection of items.

Though, to answer your question, you can accomplish what you want by:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var nameBinding = new Binding("Name")
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.Default,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };

        var ageBinding = new Binding("Age")
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.Default,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };

        var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = "Name",
            Binding = nameBinding
        });
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = "Age",
            Binding = ageBinding
        });
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Info>
        {
            new Info
            {
                Name = "Name 1",
                Age = "100"
            }
        };

        MainGrid.Children.Add(dataGrid);
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note** that `MainGrid` is the name of the container that you want to add the `DataGrid` to.